# responsive pie chart with fusioncharts

Tags: javascript, php, responsive-design, fusioncharts

I want to make my fusionchart pie chart responsive, so I follow some guide here : 
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/FirstChart/ChangeSize.html
I follow the instructions in the 'Dynamic resize feature of charts' section.

But when the page loaded, my chart flatten out (no height).
[image: my chart flatten]

When I resize the browser, the chart size was sucessfully responsive, but I get a very small pie chart
[image: very small pie]

Why was my chart flatten when the page first load? (I have to resize the browser first to see the chart). And why I get a very small chart?

Here's my code

```
<body style="height:100%;">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="chartContainer" style="height:100%;">
                FusionCharts XT will load here!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
        var myChart = new FusionCharts({
            "type": "pie2d",
            "dataFormat": "jsonurl",
            "dataSource": "pie.json",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        });
        myChart.render("chartContainer");
    });
</script>
```

And here's my pie.json :

```
{
"chart":{
    "caption":"Rasio Pendapatan Aeronautika & Non-Aeronautika",
    "subCaption":"Januari-Juni 2014",
    "paletteColors":"#008ee4,#6baa01,#f8bd19,#e44a00,#33bdda",
    "bgAlpha":"0",
    "borderAlpha":"20",
    "use3DLighting":"0",
    "showShadow":"0",
    "enableSmartLabels":"0",
    "startingAngle":"0",
    "showPercentValues":"1",
    "showPercentInTooltip":"0",
    "decimals":"3"},
    "data":
    [
            {
                "label":"Non-Aeronautika",
                "value":"534.973.345.227\r",
                "link":"newchart-jsonurl-naero.json"
            },
            {
                "label":"Aeronautika",
                "value":"960.429.586.179\r",
                "link":"newchart-jsonurl-aero.json"
            }
    ]
```

}

Could you point my mistake?

Thanks for your attention, your help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this issue in specific to any browser? Works in Chrome/FireFox

Please find the DropBox link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44972996/pie.rar

Comment: your code works perfectly, but could you please point where's my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Using AngularJS and Bootstrap.

In my HTML, I changed width="300" to width="100%"
This made my doughnut chart responsive:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="VariableInvestmentSummaryCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div fusioncharts
            width="100%"
            height="300"
            type="doughnut2d"
            dataSource="{{myDataSource}}" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 datagrid-wrapper investments"></div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
$scope.myDataSource = {
        'chart': {
            'numberPrefix': '%',
            'theme': 'fint',
            'bgColor': '#DDDDDD',
            'bgAlpha': '0'
        },
        'data':[{
            'showLabel': '0',
            'label': 'Some Name',
            'showValue': '0',
            'value': '25'
        },
        {   
            'showLabel': '0',
            'label': 'Garden Groove harbour',
            'showValue': '0',
            'value': '50'
        },
        {   
            'showLabel': '0',
            'label': 'Los Angeles Topanga',
            'showValue': '0',
            'value': '10'
        },
        {   
            'showLabel': '0',
            'label': 'Compton-Rancho Dom',
            'showValue': '0',
            'value': '10'
        },
        {   
            'showLabel': '0',
            'label': 'Daly City Serramonte',
            'showValue': '0',
            'value': '5',
            'color': '#FE0000'
        }]
    };
```